# Unpacking a Dictionary from within an ArraySlice

Tags: swift

I have an `ArraySlice<Dictionary<String, String>>` containing only one dictionary inside. This looks like the following:

```
[["high": "4", "investpercent": "6.0", "objective": "2.0", "savings": "2.0", "expenses": "1.0", "date": "2017-09-26", "low": "2"]]
```

However I wanted to manipulate the dictionary with subscripts, which is not implemented in ArraySlice. In typical slices one would, as per found question in SO, do something like:

```
let dictionary = ["a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3]

var smallerDictionary: [String: Int] = [:]

for (key, value) in dictionary.dropFirst() {
    smallerDictionary[key] = value
}

print(smallerDictionary) // ["a": 1, "c": 3]
```

Which I tried and does not work in ArraySlice.

- How do I "unpack" a dictionary from within an ArraySlice?

Comment: What restrains your from  just initialising a new array from your slice. `Array(arraySlice)` ?

Comment: I want to access values with subscripting.

Comment: Btw 0 would access the first element of the slice or of the original array? The array slice might not start at 0.

Comment: You know `.dropFirst()` will drop a random key-value pair, since dictionaries are unordered collections. In your case it did drop `"b": 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `ArraySlice` is called `slice`, use `slice.first!` or `slice[slice.startIndex]` to access the contained dictionary:

```
let slice: ArraySlice<[String:String]> = [["high": "4", "investpercent": "6.0", "objective": "2.0", "savings": "2.0", "expenses": "1.0", "date": "2017-09-26", "low": "2"]]

var smallerDictionary: [String: String] = [:]

for (key, value) in slice.first!.dropFirst() {
    smallerDictionary[key] = value
}

print(smallerDictionary)
```

**Note:**  Calling `dropFirst()` on a dictionary will give you unpredictable results because dictionaries are *unordered*.

It should go without saying that you should make sure your `ArraySlice` isn't empty before attempting to access the contained dictionary.  You can do that by explicitly checking `slice.count > 0`, `!slice.isEmpty`, or properly unwrapping `slice.first`.